# When style changes, change width of div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

I am beginner in JavaScript and it looks like I don't understand quite good if statements. I want to change background-color of div from red to blue when div becomes 500px. Hi will get 500px when I click anywhere on body tag. 
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body onclick="Go();" >
<div id="test"></div>

<style>
#test {
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script>
function Go() {
var div_test = document.getElementById('test').style;
div_test.width="500px";
}

if (document.getElementById('test').style.width="500px") {document.getElementById('test').style.cssText="background-color:blue";}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

It looks like that browser instead of understanding part in brackets of if statement as conditional "when that happened", he just create that state/style of div. When page loads div is already blue.

Comment: In your if statement  you're setting the width to 500 with a single =, try === for a comparison

Answer (score 1):

In your statement

```
if(document.getElementById('test').style.width="500px")
```

it should be

```
if(document.getElementById('test').style.width == "500px")
```

In javascript you have to user `==` or `===` as operator for comparing values

In addition, if you want to have a blue background when the element width became `500px` you will have two options

1- Add an interval

```
function Go() {
    var div_test = document.getElementById('test').style;
    div_test.width="500px";
}

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('test').style.width="500px") { 
        document.getElementById('test').style.cssText="background-color:blue";
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 500);
```

2 - just move your statement to your `Go()` Function (you will not need the if statement anymore)

```
function Go() {
    var div_test = document.getElementById('test').style;
    div_test.width="500px";
    document.getElementById('test').style.cssText= " background-color:blue";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But still I don't get blue color for div when he become 500px.

Comment: You have to rethink your logic. You can have a timer checking when the width become 500px or you can move the block straight to the if statement.

Comment: Could you give me an example?